# What’s the best way to check if a list contains an item other than specified item?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, lambda, foreach

Lets say I have a list and I want to search for an item with value “apple”.

```
List<String> items = new Arraylist<>():
```

I want to return **false** if *items* contains at least one element other than the item mentioned (“apple”), **true** if all items in the list are “apples”.

Comment: loop through it and check

Comment: So you want to find out whether the list contains item “apple”? Or if all elements are equal to “apple”?

Comment: I want to return false if list items contains value other than “apple”. 
True if all items in the list are “apples”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Stream IPA** you can achieve that by using terminal operation [`allMath()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) that takes a *predicate* (*function represented by boolean condition*) and checks whether all elements in the stream match with the given *predicate*.

The code will look like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> items1 = List.of("apple", "apple", "apple"); // expected true
    List<String> items2 = List.of("apple", "orange"); // expected false

    System.out.println(items1.stream().allMatch(item -> item.equals("apple")));
    System.out.println(items2.stream().allMatch(item -> item.equals("apple")));
}
```

**output**

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
return items.stream().anyMatch(s -> !s.equals("apple"));
```

or cute but a little less obvious:

```
return items.stream().allMatch("apple"::equals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use python but, I think is something like that:

list_entrance = input()

new_list = []

**for cycle in list_entrance:
if cycle != "apple":
print("falce")
else:
continue**

If you want of course you can "append" a items in "new_list".
I don't know full condition on your task.

Answer (score 0):

Just to say your ArrayList should be defined like this:

```
List items = new ArrayList<>();
```

You missed out some caps in the question.

For the solution you could just loop through the list and check:

```
for (int x = 0; x<items.size(); x++){
    if (! items.get(x).equals("apple")){
        return false;
    } 
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html), in order not to have duplicate items.

`Collectors` can also return `Set`:

```
Set<String> distinct = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```